# How to create a restrequest step programmatically?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm currently trying to build testCases programmatically.

Each new resource from the input swagger has to have it's corresponding testCase.

I manage to detect which resource has no testCase, I can create the testCase, but I have a problem when it's about to create the testStep.

I'm currently doing the following process :

```html
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.RestRequestStepFactory

 // create the test case
 tc = current_suite.addNewTestCase(resource) 
 // add a restrequest step
 log.info tc.getClass()
 
 tc.addTestStep(RestRequestStepFactory.RESTREQUEST_TYPE , "Request 1" )
```

This ALMOST works ! but when it reaches the testStep creation, I have a pop up "New RestRequest" opening in readyAPI asking me to 'select existing request or REST method, or create a new request'.

How can I do this step programmatically ?

Thanks for any help

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to proceed. In fact I wanted to create automatically a testCase with a testStep from the resources freshly updated with a new version of my swagger input file. I proceeded as follows:
I get the list of resources :

```
restServiceList = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getInterfaceList()
```

From each resource, I get the list of APIs it contains:

```
    restServiceList.each{
    inter -> 
    inter.each{
        // pour chaque bloc de ressources, on va recuperer la liste des API exposees
        ops = it.getOperationList()
        found = false
        ops.find(){
            // on compare le nom de l'API on nom du test - si ca matche, on sort
            //log.info it.getName()

            if(it.getName() == tc.getName())
            {
                // API trouvee, on recupere la liste des requetes
                reqList = it.getRequestList()
                found = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for each API request, I create the corresponding testStep

```
    reqList.each{
    restRequest ->
    testStepConfig = RestRequestStepFactory.createConfig( restRequest, tc.getName() );
    testStepConfig.setName("Request 1") // Attention, voir ce que ca donne sur une resource multiple !

    // log.info "testStepConfig = " + testStepConfig.toString()
    // ajout du step dans le testCase
    tc.addTestStep( testStepConfig )}
```

Additionally I created custom properties related to the request parameters (as my APIs had common parameters)

`def requestParameters = testStepConfig.config.restRequest.parameters.entryList ...`

This works quite well.